# How to JOIN multiple tables and return results with NULL values too

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to join 4 tables and one of the tables doesn't have all the matching ID's BUT I still need to show the results of the join and even for the rows that didn't have a corresponding ID.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

Example tables:

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, ts DateTime, tbl2_id INT, price DECIMAL(4,2), tbl3_id INT, tbl4_id INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1, '2013-07-25 09:30:00', 10, 10.25, 1);
    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2, '2013-07-25 10:25:00', 20, 25.25, 1);
    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(3, '2013-07-25 11:45:00', 30, 30.15, 2);
    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(4, '2013-07-25 13:31:00', 40, 80.40, 2);

    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, symbol VARCHAR(25), tbl1_id int)

    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(10, 'XYZ', 1);
    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(20, 'ABC', 2);
    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(30, 'RST', 3);
    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(40, 'EFG', 4);

    DECLARE @Table3 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, exch VARCHAR(25))

    INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(1, 'A');
    INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(2, 'B');
    INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(3, 'C');
    INSERT INTO @Table3 VALUES(4, 'D');

    DECLARE @Table4 TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, int tbl1_id, cnt INT)

    INSERT INTO @Table4 VALUES(1, 2, 19);
    INSERT INTO @Table4 VALUES(2, 4, 2013);
```

Example Query:

```
    SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.ts, tbl2.symbol, IFNULL(tbl3.cnt,0) AS cnt

    FROM TABLE1 tbl1

    JOIN TABLE2 tbl2
    ON tbl1.tbl2_id = tbl2.id

    JOIN TABLE3 tbl3
    ON tbl3.id = tbl1.tbl3_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 tbl4
    ON tbl1.tbl4_id = tbl4.id

    WHERE tbl1.ts BETWEEN '2013-07-25 09:30:00 AND '2013-07-25 16:00:00'
    AND tbl1.price >= 15.00
    LIMIT 1000;
```

So basically what I'm trying to do is if tbl4 doesn't have a tbl1_id I'd still want to see the result from table1 BUT show a 0 value for Cnt...when i run this query I'm getting a bunch of duplicate entries and the data isn't looking right.

Comment: Try joining the tables one at a time to Table 1 to see where the problem is.

Comment: i have my issue is with with tbl4...i doesn't have a corresponding ID for each ID in tbl1 but I still want to show the results with 0 as the cnt value when there is no ID match for tbl1 and tbl4

Comment: Instead of a Left outer join do right join on table 4.  That will include all records from table 4 and pair up the ones that have matches

Comment: Your sample data doesn't work. Also this is not MySQL. Is it SQL Server? Please provide sample data via http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

You are only returning the one with matches from the left hand side of the join.  Change the join with table 4 to right join and it will return all the records from the right regardless.  I know that was an example query that doesn't work with fake data. But I have to work with what you give me.  This probably wont work through copy and paste, but the theory is correct, you just gotta modify it.  If you give more detailed information I will tailor it to that.

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.ts, tbl2.symbol, IFNULL(tbl3.cnt,0) AS cnt

    FROM TABLE1 tbl1

    JOIN TABLE2 tbl2
    ON tbl1.tbl2_id = tbl2.id

    JOIN TABLE3 tbl3
    ON tbl3.id = tbl1.tbl3_id

    RIGHT JOIN TABLE4 tbl4
    ON tbl1.tbl4_id = tbl4.id

    WHERE tbl1.ts BETWEEN '2013-07-25 09:30:00 AND '2013-07-25 16:00:00'
    AND tbl1.price >= 15.00
    LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be a `LEFT JOIN` as the OP requirement?

Comment: @Akash because he wants all the records from table 4 regardless.  Hence when you all other joins table 4 you right join it which gives you all of table 4 even if no records join up with it.  The right hand table of the join give you all records and if any from the previous joins match the criteria then it will join those with the records from the right(table 4)

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** In your sample code you gave a mix of SQL Server and MySql syntax:

- `DECLARE TABLE`, `CLUSTERED` are SQL Server features
- `IFNULL()`, `LIMIT` are MySql's

**Secondly** `cnt` column is in Table4 not in Table3 so `IFNULL(tbl3.cnt,0)` is not going to fly.

**Thirdly** your last edit when you changed `tbl1.id = tbl4.tbl1_id` to `tbl1.tbl4_id = tbl4.id` doesn't add up with the rest of your sample data since you don't have values in your insert statements either for `tbl3_id` or for newly introduced `tbl4_id`. And `tbl1_id` column now seems to be unnecessary.

*Therefore IMHO you need to revisit and correct your sample data. And posting desired output might also help you to get your answer.*

---

Now here is a query that works and based on your data schema before your last edit. *It will successfully work both in MySql and SQL Server except for the `LIMIT` part*

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.ts, t2.symbol, COALESCE(t4.cnt, 0) cnt
  FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.tbl1_id JOIN Table3 t3
    ON t1.tbl3_id = t3.id LEFT JOIN Table4 t4
    ON t1.id = t4.tbl1_id
 WHERE t1.ts BETWEEN '2013-07-25 09:30:00' AND '2013-07-25 16:00:00'
   AND t1.price >= 15.00
 LIMIT 1000 -- LIMIT will work only in MySql
```

Output:

```
| ID |                          TS | SYMBOL |  CNT |
----------------------------------------------------
|  2 | July, 25 2013 10:25:00+0000 |    ABC |   19 |
|  3 | July, 25 2013 11:45:00+0000 |    RST |    0 | 
|  4 | July, 25 2013 13:31:00+0000 |    EFG | 2013 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/790e9/13)** (MySql) demo
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/790e9/3)** (SQL Server) demo